# How to deal with invalid character(s) in column names when using databricks autoloader for csv?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

I am attempting to setup a databricks autoloader stream to read a large amount of csv files, however I get the error
`Found invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=" in the column names of your schema.` due to the .csv column names containing spaces. The message suggests enabling column mapping by `setting table property 'delta.columnMapping.mode' to 'name'` and refers me to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-column-mapping) docs page, however I cannot see a way to implement this.

This is the code for setting up the stream:

```
stream = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")\
        .option('cloudFiles.format', 'csv')\
        .option('cloudFiles.schemaLocation', delta_loc)\
        .option("rescuedDataColumn", "_rescued_data")\
        .option('header', 'true')\
        .option('delimiter', '|')\
        .option('pathGlobFilter', f"*{file_code}*.csv")\
        .load(data_path)
```

Answer (score 3):

We have this issue in a couple cases so we do this in the reader:
`.transform(lambda df: remove_bda_chars_from_columns(df))`

And the UDF is:

```
def remove_bda_chars_from_columns(df):
    return  df.select([col(x).alias(x.replace(" ", "_").replace("/", "").replace("%", "pct").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")) for x in df.columns])
```